# Moving lines up into a file with python

Tags: python

The text file is appending data with tabs or spaces for each column, I want to correct them and append in the same row respectively,
Is there any way to transform this text file:

What I am getting
[image]

into that:

The result I want
[image]

My code is:

```
query = "SELECT date_ FROM customers_payments7 WHERE date_ >= %s AND date_ <= %s"
mycursor.execute(query,(from_date,to_date))
for cursor in mycursor:
     file.write(f"{cursor[0]}\n")


query = "SELECT customer_surname FROM customers_payments7 WHERE date_ >= %s AND date_ <= %s"
mycursor.execute(query,(from_date,to_date))
for cursor in mycursor:
     file.write(f"\t\t{cursor[0]}\n")


query = "SELECT amount FROM customers_payments7 WHERE date_ >= %s AND date_ <= %s"
mycursor.execute(query,(from_date,to_date))
for cursor in mycursor:
       file.write(f"\t\t\t\t{cursor[0]}\n")

query = "SELECT description FROM customers_payments7 WHERE date_ >= %s AND date_ <= %s"
mycursor.execute(query,(from_date,to_date))
for cursor in mycursor:
     file.write(f"\t\t\t\t\t\t{cursor[0]}\n")



file.close()
os.system("notepad.exe BasicTextFile.txt")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're querying one field at a time from the same table with the same `where` rules, just query all at once

```
query = "SELECT date_, customer_surname, amount, description FROM customers_payments7 WHERE date_ >= %s AND date_ <= %s"
mycursor.execute(query, (from_date, to_date))
for row in mycursor:
    file.write("\t".join(row))
```

---

***old answer***

You need to save each query results in a list, then zip to get each row from all the columns, and write it

```
cols = []

query = "SELECT date_ FROM customers_payments7 WHERE date_ >= %s AND date_ <= %s"
mycursor.execute(query, (from_date, to_date))
cols.append([value for value, in mycursor])

# ...

for row in zip(*cols):
    file.write("\t".join(row))
```